# difference between copying 16-bytes and 256-bytes to shared memory

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm writing a CUDA program. The code copies pinned memory to shared memory, by pinned memory I mean memory allocated with `cudaHostAlloc(., ., cudaHostAllocMapped)`. It takes **600us** to copy **16** bytes and **8ms** to copy **256** bytes. Why so huge difference?

My code looks like:

```
__global__
void kernel_func(char* dict, int dict_len)
{
    __shared__ char s_dict[256];

    /* dict_len = 16; */
    if(threadIdx.x == 0) {// copy once for each block
        memcpy((unsigned char*)s_dict, (unsigned char*)dict, dict_len);
    }
    __syncthreads(); 
}

kernel_func<<<32, 128>>>("256 bytes pinned memory", 256);
```

The environment: GTX650 + CUDA 6.5 + Win7-32bit

Comment: `600 us - 16 bytes` * 16 -> `9.6 ms - 256 bytes`. `9.6 ms ~= 8 ms` not so *huge*.

Comment: 600µs is much very higher than expected. Is the memory copy doing 16 x  1 byte read, 1 byte write. If dict is 16 byte aligned then you can use a single LD.128 to read and LDS.128 to write the data; otherwise, the best option is to have the first 16 threads load the data in one instruction and store the data in one instruction. My expectation is <20 µs for 16 bytes. Pinned system memory is not cached in the GPU L2 or L1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 256 bytes is 16 times what you previously copied (16 bytes)

Now **16 bytes** took **600us**

And **16 times** that is **9600us** Which is close to the **8000us** you observed (1ms = 1000us)

Comment: Aha :)  Why the kernel transfers 16bytes every time? Any document about the 16-bytes?

Comment: No that's just coincidental on the numbers you said in your original question. Its just: **16 bytes = 600us** therefore **1 byte = 37.5us** and then therefor **256 bytes = 9600us = 9.6ms ~ 8ms**